# What is the language of this simple DFA with 4 states?

Tags: regular-expressions

I wanted to say that the language is the set of strings that end with "101" but unfortunately it does not work. Take for example "110101",
which is not accept by the dfa.

[image]

Comment: It has a complex regular expression as $(1+(0+\epsilon+1(1+011)*0(0+10))(0+1(1+011)*0(0+10))*1)(1+011)*01$. How could I say that? I gave it to an online DFA to regular expression converter like [this one][1]. I think regular expression always can give you better information about the language and the DFA you gave does not have a simple language for sure.


  [1]: https://ivanzuzak.info/noam/webapps/fsm2regex/

Comment: The answer of this exercise is « strings that finish with odd number of pairs of symbols 10 and 1 after them, ```(10)^(2k+1) 1``` where k is any integer»

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### Description in plain English

A binary string is accepted by the DFA iff its longest suffix that looks like $1010\cdots1$ has an odd number of $0$s.

In other words, A binary string is accepted by the DFA iff its longest suffix that starts and ends with 1 and alternates between 0 and 1 has an odd number of $0$s.

In other words, a binary string is accepted by the DFA iff it ends with $101$ and we will see an odd number of consecutive $01$s when we scan the string backwards from the last $0$.

More formally, a binary string is accepted by the DFA iff it ends with $101$ and the length of its longest suffix of the form $(10)^+1$  is $3 \pmod 4$.

##### Another description in plain English

A binary string is accepted by the DFA iff "it can be decomposed into a series of substrings each of which ends $101$ without containing any other instance of $101$".

This description is given in [a comment by rici](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150027/description-of-an-automaton#comment315475_150027?noredirect=1).

##### Two descriptions in regular expression

$$(0^*1^*(00^+1^*)^*101)^+$$
The above expression is also given by rici.

$$(\epsilon+0+(0+1)^*(1+00))(1010)^*101$$