# Description of an automaton

Tags: finite-automata

i'm a student and i've been searching the language description of this automaton.[image]

The states are as follows: Q = {q1, q2, q3,q4}

The alphabet is as follows: Σ = {0,1}

The start state is q1

The accepting state is q4

After some research i though i had something. Every string ending in 101 is accepted, but then i tried 10101 and it doesn't work, same things for the others states.

If someone has an another reasoning, i'll be glad to discuss it.
Thanks

Comment: Actually every string ending with 1101 is accepted, but this is not a necessary condition for a string to be accepted (think to 00101).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the language of this simple DFA with 4 states?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/150014/what-is-the-language-of-this-simple-dfa-with-4-states)

Comment: I guess it's $(0^*1^*(000^*1^*)^*101)^+$ (tested [here](https://cyberzhg.github.io/toolbox/nfa2dfa?regex=KDAqMSooMDAwKjEqKSoxMDEpKw==)), which is a binary string which can be decomposed into a series of substrings each of which ends $101$ without containing any other instance of $101$.